# using a string (from gets) directly as a variable name

Tags: ruby

Starting out my Towers of Hanoi assignment, I have

```
a = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
b = []    
c = []

puts "Type a, b, or c"
from = gets.chomp
# the user types a lower-case a
popped = from.pop
```

Now this obviously fails because pop is not a string method.

So other than

```
if from == a
    popped = a.pop
elsif from == b
    popped = b.pop
```

, is there a nice ruby shortcut to get the pop I intend?

Comment: Is `a = [6,5,4,3,2,1]` the user input? Please make more clear what the program is and what the user input is.

Comment: Question has been fixed. Crucial info got deleted before.

Comment: Well you could do a `case` statement, but that's just the same as your `if`. As far as I know there is no shortcut to get the string input to be equivalent to the variable name. (P.S. It should be `if from == a` not single =).

Comment: I'll bet you $10 that `from = a` is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

```
a = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
b = []    
c = []

puts "Type a, b, or c"
from = gets.chomp
popped = eval(from).pop
```

But `eval` is typically seen as a bad idea for security, performance, and debugging reasons.

Comment: I will investigate this eval business, and sadly, have to avoid it. Thanks

Comment: My answer below is a safer alternative to eval.

Comment: +1 Whether `eval` is a good idea or not here, Ricky answers the question and is the only one to have done so. I don't believe the downvote was justified.

Comment: It encourages bad use of eval.

Comment: Thank you everyone for reinforcing that eval is a bad idea. That's exactly why I made a note of it in my answer. But just because you shouldn't use it doesn't mean you shouldn't learn about it. Also, I suggest down voters read up on what warrants a down vote. I don't think this qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

```
options = {
  :a => [6,5,4,3,2,1]
  :b => []    
  :c => []
}

puts "Type a, b, or c"
from = gets.chomp
popped = options[from.to_sym].pop
```

I have to strongly advise you avoid the use of the method using `eval` above, as it allows the user to input arbitrary code. Use a hash instead to store all your options.

Comment: As long as we're talking about security, interning an unknown string using to_sym is also poor form as it is vulnerable to denial of service attacks. Of course, in this context it wouldn't be a concern. I'm just nitpicking.